# Workaround for Error 414 when opening file from PHP script

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP script that's outputting a CSV file and up until now I've been just using a link and passing parameters that are used to determine the output in the GET data. However recently the size of the data increased and now that code gets `Error 414 - Request URI too Large`. I tried using a hidden form to do it with POST but it just reloaded the page and didn't supply a prompt to download the file and all of the suggestions I've been able to find online about doing it with AJAX suggest using a link with GET data instead. Does anyone know a workaround that will have the browser still let the user easily download the data?

Presently I'm just setting the href attribute of a `<a>` tag.

`$("#exportCSV").attr('href', "myscript.php/?data=" + exportData);`

exportData has become too long for GET data but I want to maintain the behavior where if you click on a link that has say a CSV file being outputted the browser provides a download dialog for the user.

Comment: Please show your code, it's hard to tell what's going on from your description.

Comment: I assume you are reading the paramters from `$_GET`, you need to switch it to read from `$_POST` or if you want to support both then you need check and see which source you need to use based on the request method, or decide how you want to merge them into a single set of params before using them to process things.